# Wait for user response in a Dialog before continuing execution

Tags: android, dialog

Im using Geocoder to get coordinates from an Adress. When I get the answer from Geocoder, I present a Dialog to the user so he can choice the correct adress (can be a lot of streets with the same name all around the world). This is the method:

```
    private LatLng parsearDireccion(String direccion) {

    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(c);

    try {
        adress = (ArrayList<Address>) coder.getFromLocationName(direccion, 30);

        if(adress.size()>0){
            AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    LeaveParamsActivity.this);

            builderSingle.setTitle(getString(R.string.selectaddress));
            final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    c,
                    android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
            for(int i=0;i<adress.size();i++){
                String ciudad=adress.get(i).getLocality();
                String calle=adress.get(i).getThoroughfare();
                if(calle==null){
                    calle=adress.get(i).getAddressLine(0);

                }


                if(ciudad==null){
                    ciudad=adress.get(i).getSubLocality();

                }
                if(ciudad==null){
                    ciudad=adress.get(i).getAdminArea();

                }
                arrayAdapter.add(calle+","+ciudad);
            }

            builderSingle.setAdapter(arrayAdapter,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    Address location = adress.get(which);
                    lat = location.getLatitude();
                    lon = location.getLongitude();
                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });
    builderSingle.show();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    LatLng coords=new LatLng(lat, lon);
    return coords;
}
```

The problem is, I get the return before the user clicks on the Dialog options...and so, coordinates are null. How could I wait for the user to click one of the options in the Dialog, and AFTER THAT continue with the execution of the program?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

make it void and remove the return and just make another method to return the LatLng and put it in the dialog and just use it as a variable

Comment: Im afraid i dont understand...The LatLng comes from the user selection on the Dialog. The user selects the proper street (Adress object) in the Dialog, and then I get the LatLng from the Adress the user selected.

Comment: so when they click store the lat and lon and make a public LatLng, or even static that you can access where you need it

Comment: The problem is I need the LatLng inmediately after I present the Dialog...and the execution of the program doesn't wait the user to click before continuing...

Comment: I've ended putting all the code in the onClick method...maybe its not good practice...but now it works.